# HTML5 video wrong height in flexbox

Tags: html, css, video, flexbox, responsive

On a [recent website I made](https://birjolaxew.github.io/flippy.js/demos#twitch-minimize-video), I've included a video:

```
<video autoplay loop muted 
  src="video.mp4">
    Your browser doesn't seem to support videos :(
</video>
```

This video is placed inside a `display: flex` parent.
Since I want it to be responsive, I then have this in my CSS:

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This [functions fine in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fueh4.png).
In [Chrome, on the other hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blg32.png), the following seems to happen:

- The element's width is set as expected.
- The height of the element is set based on what the video's width *would have been* if the element hadn't limited its size.

How can I fix this so that the video respects the width of the `<video>` element (in a responsive manner), and the height is determined by the aspect ratio of the video and the width of the element?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video autoplay loop muted 
    src="https://birjolaxew.github.io/flippy.js/assets/video/train.mp4">
      Your browser doesn't seem to support videos :(
  </video>
  <div class="content">
    Content below video goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be due the flex.

Removing `display:flex` from the `.container` will fix it.

If you need the `flex` then add `flex-direction:column` to the `.container` since that is the way you actually use it.

---

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video autoplay loop muted 
    src="https://birjolaxew.github.io/flippy.js/assets/video/train.mp4">
      Your browser doesn't seem to support videos :(
  </video>
  <div class="content">
    Content below video goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as you answered (although w/o the solution) :) Thank you!